# How to run Mocha tests written in TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js

Setup: I have a Node project (pure Node, no browser bits) written in TypeScript. I can use the TypeScript compiler (`tsc`) from the `typescript` module to compile the code. So far so good.

However, I want to write tests using Mocha, and that's where I'm having trouble. I tried `--compilers ts:typescript`, but I keep getting errors like:

```
error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'compilers'.
```

It looks like the command line to `mocha` ends up being passed to `tsc`, which is obviously not good.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

For anybody who has tried and had problems with *typescript-require* you may want to try [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node).

```
$ npm install -g ts-node
$ mocha --require ts-node/register src/**/*.spec.ts
```

It also appears that there has been some [ongoing discussion](https://github.com/theblacksmith/typescript-require/issues/36) about deprecating typescript-require in favor of ts-node.

Comment: Using ts-node, I have difficulties doing code coverage for the tests using Istanbul (after running the mocha tests in gulp). Istanbul doesn't seem to be able to remap to the original TS files (using Istanbul remapper). Any possible solutions for this?

Comment: To avoid a lot of complications I've resorted to compiling my tests which are written in TypeScript with tsc as a precursor to running tests and making sure to generate source maps. This allows me to debug my tests in VS Code and doesn't rely on typescript-require or ts-node.

Comment: `typescript-require` is already deprecated https://github.com/theblacksmith/typescript-require/issues/34#issuecomment-230915434

Comment: What is test.ts in relation to 'src/**/*.spec.ts'?

Comment: @jpierson can you make your process a full answer?

Comment: For people getting **unable to compile TypeScript**: Try including `"include": ["**/*.ts"]` on tsconfig.json https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/168#issuecomment-257009461

Comment: @Bob I'll try to expound on what I arrived at when I get a chance but I haven't worked in that TypeScript project for a few months now and I'm not sure when I'll get a chance to get back into it.

Comment: @JamelToms it seems like `test.ts` is not required, and the last part is the pattern to find all tests in project. this worked for me: `mocha --require ts-node/register src/**/*.spec.ts`

Comment: If you are looking at this now, take a gander at https://github.com/piotrwitek/ts-mocha. Makes this even easier.

Comment: This seems to no longer work with mocha, it gives me the error `Unknown file extension ".ts"` with the latest version.

Comment: @justin.m.chase [New "loader"](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/4726#issuecomment-903213780). Set "`"loader": "ts-node/esm"` in `.mocharc.json` instead of `"require"`".

Comment: @JamelToms, many people use .test.ts instead of .spec.ts as the convention for test files, especially Jest users.

Answer (score 10):

**Don't use this answer. typescript-require is unmaintained, and ts-node is its replacement. Leaving this answer here for posterity.**

Found it. The `typescript` module is actually like a "main" function; it runs the compiler as soon as the module is loaded. Not very nice design.

I poked at Mocha's acceptance tests, which show how to use a custom compiler for `foo` files. They wire it up via the `require.extensions` mechanism. I was halfway through writing a module that just calls `tsc` on the command line when I realized that somebody must have done this before. So it's very simple:

```
$ npm install typescript-require --save-dev
$ mocha --compilers ts:typescript-require
```

Comment: I don't really think this works well.  You can see [my related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996110/combine-mocha-typescript-and-watch) to understand why.

Comment: Don't look at this one. The project is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks @DmitriiSorin. I've edited my answer, and submitted a PR to the typescript-require README to announce this more clearly. Also I just noticed that I originally asked the question, so I could move the green check mark :D

Comment: `--compilers` is also deprecated ... >< aaahhh use `--require ts-node/register` they say.. and/or with `--require source-map-support/register`

Answer (score 7):

There is a newer solution for using `mocha` with TypeScript, and it's using `tsx` node loader.

First, install the `tsx` package with the following command:

```bash
npm install --save-dev tsx
```

Then, create a `.mocharc.json` file with the following content:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/mocharc.json",
  "require": "tsx"
}
```

Now you're ready to use `mocha` with TypeScript.

#### References

- [Mocha Configuration file](https://mochajs.org/#configuring-mocha-nodejs)
- [Why is `tsx` Better than `ts-node`](https://github.com/privatenumber/tsx#how-is-tsx-different-from-ts-node)

Comment: Damn, that is a nice answer!

Answer (score 6):

Using the latest version of *Mocha* and *ts-node* I was getting an *Unexpected token* import issue. Using the below settings with [ts-mocha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mocha) worked for me:

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "files": [
        "src/main.ts"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "types": ["mocha"],
        "module": "commonjs"
    }
}
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "mocha": "ts-mocha -p library/tsconfig.json library/test/**/*.ts"
  },
```

launch.json

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Mocha Tests",
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/ts-mocha/bin/ts-mocha",
        "--timeout", "999999",
        "-p",
        "${workspaceFolder}/library/tsconfig.json",
        "${workspaceFolder}/library/test/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
}
```

and gulp.js just incase you want to use gulp too

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const ts = require('gulp-typescript');
const mocha = require('gulp-mocha');

const tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');

gulp.task('build', () => tsProject.src()
  .pipe(tsProject())
  .js.pipe(gulp.dest('dist')));

gulp.task('test', () => gulp.src('test/*.spec.ts')
  .pipe(mocha({
    reporter: 'nyan',
    require: ['ts-node/register'],
  })));
/* single command to hook into VS Code */
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('build', 'test'));
```

Comment: Using ts-mocha worked for me as well. I added my solution to https://stackoverflow.com/a/58186015/7322030

Answer (score 2):

Configure `ts-node` as your loader.

Add `.mocharc.js` to project root:

```
module.exports = {
  loader: 'ts-node/esm',
};
```

Ensure you have `ts-node` installed:  `npm install ts-node -D`. [Source here](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/4726#issuecomment-903213780).

Comment: Cannot parse the mocharc.js unless renamed to mocharc.cjs and then cannot import anything in a project with typescript and javascript.

Comment: If you can't parse .mocharc.js file then that may be a separate issue that I'd resolve first.