# Combine mocha, Typescript (and watch)

Tags: typescript, mocha.js

I've created a project where I want to use mocha to test my Typescript code.  If I do this:

```
mocha ts/test --compilers ts:typescript-require
```

After I make a change, it will fail with a message like:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'mocha'.
```

This is strange because if I just run `tsc` everything is fine (I have all my type definitions and I'm using a `tsconfig.json` file).  I also installed `typescript-require` for `mocha`.

But each time I run the command after that, it works?!?  But if I put `mocha` in watch mode:

```
mocha -w ts/test --compilers ts:typescript-require
```

Then it works the first time through but fails after that.  Ugh!  Any suggestions on how to get a robust setup involving `mocha` and Typescript so that I can test and watch?

Comment: Both `tsc` and `typescript-require` are pointing to version 1.6.2, BTW.

Comment: Why don't you use gulp or grunt? It makes thinks much easier. Here is an example of gulp build with mocha chai and sinon https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/gulpfile.js

Comment: I do use grunt (and would be fine with gulp too).  But it just seems like overkill (that file you linked to is 175 lines long) just to run some tests.

Furthermore, this whole thing smells like a bug.  There is something stateful going on here that shouldn't be.

Comment: @MichaelTiller I agree this feels like a bug. Why aren't we allowed to use the default TypeScript compiler? It should be simpler than having someone go out and create a whole new runtime. This post is over 3 years old, is there anyone that has a solution with a `tsc` compiler and not ts-node (still thank you @blakeembrey for the solution, I will use it until I can find a default `tsc` solution <3)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I wrote `ts-node` after running into a similar use-case (https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node). I needed to run tests with different test runners and compiling to a different directory doesn't cut it because I also like inlining the test fixtures. It's been expanded into feature complete node runtime for TypeScript (including a CLI with a cool little `.type` command feature). There's an example in the README for executing it with Mocha.

It's all in-memory right now, but eventually it will be expanded with additional flags to make it reasonable for production usage (E.g. no runtime overhead, just compilation startup). Let me know how it goes for you!

Comment: I tried it out.  Works very nicely.  I added a `mocha.opts` file to my `test` directory and everything works perfectly if I just run `mocha` in the root directory of my repository.  Thanks!

Comment: @blakeembrey: Is it possible to provide an alternate `tsconfig.json` (`tsconfig.tsnode.json`) when calling from mocha? My main `tsconfig.json` uses `"module": "es2015"`, but I want to override for ts-node with `"module": "commonjs"`.

Comment: any video on this subject?

Comment: @Ralph You can use the `--project` option, see the README for more information.

Comment: @blakeembrey `inlining the test fixtures` - what do you mean?

Comment: `ts-node` doesn't work with ESM :/ Alternative `tsx` works with ESM, but doesn't check types :/

Answer (score 11):

this command watch typescript test changes and fire them (ts-node should be installed):

```
"scripts": {
"watch": "mocha -r ts-node/register test/*Test.ts  --watch --watch-extensions ts"
}
```

Comment: @BartoszKP & @Alex it's not working.. i am using `mocha 7.2` with `mocha -r ts-node/register tests/*.ts --watch --watch-extensions ts` but it's not re-running test cases on test file changes

Comment: @Ritesh as you can see, my edit was purely editorial, I have no idea what this question is about, nor I understand the answer. Stil, I believe you should create a new question clearly stating your problem, instead of following up in the comments section.

Answer (score 10):

For me I had to add a prefix like `**/`

`mocha -r ts-node/register "test/**/*.ts" --watch --watch-files **/*`

And for multiple specific folders/files:

`mocha -r ts-node/register "test/**/*.ts" --watch --watch-files src/**/*,test/**/*`

Answer (score 3):

**--extensions** flag is no longer working now on **Mocha 8**.

use **--watch-files**

```
"scripts": {
    "watch": "mocha -r ts-node/register test/*Test.ts  --watch --watch-files *.ts"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Mocha 7, `--watch` flag will only work if you have defined either `--watch-files` or `--extension`. So you can choose any of the following config :

```
"scripts": {
    "watch": "mocha -r ts-node/register test/*Test.ts  --watch --extensions ts"
}
```

or

```
"scripts": {
    "watch": "mocha -r ts-node/register test/*Test.ts  --watch --watch-files test"
}
```

From the Mocha official documentation :

> --watch, -w Rerun tests on file changes.
>
> The --watch-files and --watch-ignore options can be used to control
>   which files are watched for changes.
>
> Tests may be rerun manually by typing ⓡ ⓢ ⏎ (same shortcut as
>   nodemon).
>
> ## --watch-files  New in v7.0.0
>
> List of paths or globs to watch when --watch is set. If a file
>   matching the given glob changes or is added or removed mocha will
>   rerun all tests.
>
> If the path is a directory all files and subdirectories will be
>   watched.
>
> By default all files in the current directory having one of the
>   extensions provided by --extension and not contained in the
>   node_modules or .git folders are watched.
>
> The option can be given multiple times. The option accepts a
>   comma-delimited list: --watch-files a,b is equivalent to --watch-files
>   a --watch-files b

Answer (score 1):

I created a .mocharc.json with content:

```
{
  "extension": ["ts"],
  "spec": "test/**/*.ts",
  "require": "ts-node/register"
}
```

Now I can run mocha either a single run or in watch mode:

```sh
$ npx mocha
or
$ npx mocha --watch
```

Of course I can add this to package.json as script.