# TypeScript external node modules sometimes transpile to module.exports and exports

Tags: node.js, typescript, commonjs

I'm in the process of converting my node app to use TypeScript external modules.  Everything works fine when running the app but when converting some of my .ts files, the mocha tests "explode" due to `SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word`.

After much debugging, I've found the following reproducible failure case.  I have a simple autoRoles.ts file that defines the available user roles.  Prior to using external modules, it looked like:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/backend_typings.d.ts" />

module.exports.roles = {
  // role definitions
}
```

Now after the conversion:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/backend_typings.d.ts" />

export let roles = {
  // role definitions
}
```

When running the mocha tests, it generates the following error:

```
>> Mocha exploded!
>> SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
>>     at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
>>     at Module._compile (module.js:413:25)
>>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
>>     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
>>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
>>     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
>>     at require (module.js:384:17)
>>     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/abc/esupport/code/asp_v4/lib/models/userRole.ts:77:17)
>>     at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
>>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
>>     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
>>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
>>     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
>>     at require (module.js:384:17)
>>     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/abc/esupport/code/asp_v4/lib/users/lib/ssoAuth.ts:7:17)
>>     at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
>>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
>>     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
>>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
>>     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
>>     at require (module.js:384:17)
>>     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/abc/esupport/code/asp_v4/lib/users/index.ts:5:31)
```

I can flip between the old implementation and the new implementation for the autoRoles.ts file and get mocha to pass and fall, respectively.  Note, there is a `require('<path>/autoRoles')` on line 77 of userRoles.ts.

When comparing between the transpiled versions, the only difference is that the old version uses 'module.exports' and the new one just has 'exports'.

Old:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/backend_typings.d.ts" />
exports.roles = {
  // role definitions
}
```

New:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/backend_typings.d.ts" />
module.exports.roles = {
  // role definitions
}
```

So I'm aware that "exports" is just a shortcut to "module.exports" so I can't explain why this is causing mocha to fail but I do know that if I switch between the two and change nothing else, mocha "explodes".  I've also noticed that for other transpiled modules, tsc sometimes uses "module.exports" and sometimes uses "exports".  Why the difference and more importantly, why is mocha exploding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more debugging, I found that mocha wasn't using the generated .js source code files that tsc transpiled.  I'm not sure exactly how but it was trying to execute the "export var roles" located in the .ts file and "export" is a reserved word.

I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977722/how-to-run-mocha-tests-written-in-typescript), which indicated to me that mocha is trying to do it's own transpiling.  That guy suggested to use "typescript-require" but that package looks like in the middle of being deprecated in favor of "ts-node".  So I changed my grunt-ts config to look like:

```
mochaTest: {
    test: {
        options: {
            reporter: 'spec',
            require: [
                'ts-node/register'
            ]
        },
        src: ['lib/test/**/*.spec.js']
    }
},
```

This works but I'd be more than happy to have someone shed some light on what mocha was doing.  Also, why was mocha successfully transpiling / not detecting "reserved word" in other .ts files that used export?

**Edit 10/30/2015:**

So I found out why mocha was trying to execute my .ts files.  I was stupidly importing some of them as require('/path/file.ts') where I should have left the '.ts' extension off.  I no longer need 'ts-node' in my mocha runner.  This also explains why mocha was only erroring on some of my .ts files.

Answer (score 1):

> Unexpected reserved word

Have `"use strict";` at the top of your file. You probably have a variable that is a reserved keyword. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Paving_the_way_for_future_ECMAScript_versions . TypeScript will warn on such variable names if you have that header in the file.

`module.exports.roles = {` is not the source of your error.

> I've also noticed that for other transpiled modules, tsc sometimes uses "module.exports" and sometimes uses "exports".

Its similar to the nodejs convention. Basically saving characters (bytes) the runtime needs to parse.

```
export let foo = 123;
```

Will give you

```
exports.foo = 123;
```

(because `exports == module.export` therefore `exports.foo == module.export.foo` ... as you already know). However in :

```
let foo = 123;
export = foo;
```

It does

```
var foo = 123;
module.exports = foo;
```

Because *if you reassign exports* i.e. `exports = foo` then `module.export !== exports`. So you can use `exports` for extension .... but not *assignment*.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion and explanation on "module.exports" vs "exports".  Unfortunately, "use strict" didn't solve the problem.  See my answer for what I did to fix it.