# Overriding `tsconfig.json` for ts-node in mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, tsconfig

Is it possible to override which `tsconfig.json` ts-node uses when called from mocha?

My main `tsconfig.json` contains `"module": "es2015"`, but I want to use `"module": "commonjs"` for ts-node only.

I tried this

```
mocha --compilers ts:ts-node/register,tsx:ts-node/register \
    --compilerOptions '{"module":"commonjs"}' \
    --require ts-node/register test/**/*.spec.ts*
```

but it did not work:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Module.m._compile (/usr/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:406:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .tsx] (/usr/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:409:12)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:222:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:219:14)
    at Mocha.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:487:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:458:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:146:18)
    at node.js:404:3
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You need to set the configuration through the `TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS` environment variable

Example code on an unix machine:

```
TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS='{"module":"commonjs"}' \
mocha --require ts-node/register 'test/**/*.spec.{ts,tsx}'
```

---

*Explanation extracted from the [repository documentation](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/tree/629525474fb548fddb7a90a48ab795a9199b1997#cli-and-programmatic-options)*

---

**CLI and Programmatic Options**

*Environment variable denoted in parentheses.*

- `-T, --transpile-only` Use TypeScript's faster transpileModule (`TS_NODE_TRANSPILE_ONLY`, default: false)
- `-I, --ignore [pattern]` Override the path patterns to skip compilation (`TS_NODE_IGNORE`, default: /node_modules/)
- `-P, --project [path]` Path to TypeScript JSON project file (`TS_NODE_PROJECT`)
- `-C, --compiler [name]` Specify a custom TypeScript compiler (`TS_NODE_COMPILER`, default: typescript)
- `-D, --ignore-diagnostics [code]` Ignore TypeScript warnings by diagnostic code (`TS_NODE_IGNORE_DIAGNOSTICS`)
- `-O, --compiler-options [opts]` JSON object to merge with compiler options (`TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS`)
- `--files` Load files from tsconfig.json on startup (`TS_NODE_FILES`, default: false)
- `--pretty` Use pretty diagnostic formatter (`TS_NODE_PRETTY`, default: false)
- `--skip-project` Skip project config resolution and loading (`TS_NODE_SKIP_PROJECT`, default: false)
- `--skip-ignore` Skip ignore checks (`TS_NODE_SKIP_IGNORE`, default: false)
- `--log-error` Logs errors of types instead of exit the process (`TS_NODE_LOG_ERROR`, default: false)
- `--prefer-ts-exts` Re-order file extensions so that TypeScript imports are preferred (`TS_NODE_PREFER_TS_EXTS`, default: false)

Comment: bummer that there doesn't seem to be a nice way of doing this in a way that works for both Windows and *nix.

Comment: Take a look at @Louis answer for a cross-platform support

Comment: Windows: ```cross-env TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS={\\\"module\\\":\\\"commonjs\\\"} mocha -r ts-node/register test/**/*.spec.ts --reporter=dot```

Answer (score 51):

TypeScript allows you to override a configuration file. Rather than hard-code JSON in an environment variable as mentioned in the other solutions, specify the overridden configuration path in the environment. The `TS_NODE_PROJECT` environment variable can be used for this.

```sh
TS_NODE_PROJECT='./tsconfig.commonjs.json'
```

So if your main config is:

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
   }
}
```

You can create another configuration that overrides the `module` setting.

tsconfig.commonjs.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs"
  }
}
```

When you run mocha, specify the overridden configuration to use:

```
"test": "TS_NODE_PROJECT='./tsconfig.commonjs.json' mocha -r ts-node/register test/**/*.spec.ts*"
```

This makes it very easy to further customize your `tsconfig` just for mocha testing. You can even run `ts-node` (outside of mocha) directly specifying that path:

```sh
ts-node -P tsconfig.commonjs.json -r myFile.ts
```

Comment: For Windows a small adjustment were needed:
`SET TS_NODE_PROJECT=./tsconfig.commonjs.json&& mocha -r ts-node/register test/**/*.spec.ts`

Comment: You can use cross-env (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) to make the command platform independent.

Comment: In @PerThomasson's comment, the space between `.json` and `&&` is **not** a typo, it is needed. Might save you some time :D

Comment: Nice example. It worked. Now I have another problem, My code is for browser then I have some `document.getElementById`, when I run the test I get the error `ReferenceError: document is not defined` Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: If document is not defined, you are not running in a browser, or you built for the wrong target, or you need to include a browser environment in your node runtime.

Answer (score 22):

`--compilerOptions` wont' work.

What you need to do is customize how you register `ts-node`. My case was a little bit different from yours, I wanted it to use `test/tsconfig.json`, which contained settings needed by my test code. If I just used `--require ts-node/register`, it was using a default configuration that did not contain the settings needed to run my tests.

What I did was:

1. Create a file `test/tshook.js`. It contains:

   ```
   require("ts-node").register({
     project: "test/tsconfig.json",
   });
   ```
2. I edited my `test/mocha.opts` to have:

   ```
   --require test/tshook.js
   test/**/*.ts
   ```

This should will pass the desired setting to `ts-node`:

```
require("ts-node").register({
  compilerOptions: {
    module: "commonjs",
  },
});
```

Comment: This breaks breakpoints in Webstorm debug. Probably something wrong in maps file. Note that breakpoints break under in `./src/` files while under `./test` they work fine. Anything can be done about it? I mean if I don't do this `--require test/tshook.js` - breakpoints work as expected.

Comment: Here's how it looks: I tried to `stepInto` but it skipped a lot of functions, and stopped somewhere in random place. Without `tshooks` this works as expected . https://static.pychat.org/photo/WLdZb0pO_Mon_Jul_31_170826_2017.gif

Comment: In case anyone else is wondering how mocha finds "test/mocha.opts", that path is the default path for this file. In my case I had a different folder name for tests, which was causing problems.

Answer (score 7):

In package.json - scripts section:

```
"test": "TS_NODE_PROJECT=src mocha"
```

picks up my tsconfig.json in the src directory of my project, overriding the default tsconfig.json.

OP can achieve same by using test instead of src

Comment: I have to specify path to the tsconfig.json file i.e. <root>/test/tsconfig.json to make it work

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me on windows

```
set TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS={\"module\":\"commonjs\"} && mocha -r ts-node/register test/unit/*.test.ts
```

This was the error that prompted me to use that solution

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import 'mocha';
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use ts-mocha (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mocha)

#### Example

package.json

```
"test": "ts-mocha -p test/tsconfig.cjs.json test/**/*.test.ts"
```

test/tsconfig.cjs.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs"
  }
}
```

Comment: ts-mocha seems deprecated

Answer (score 3):

While there doesn't seem to be a unified linux/windows command line phrasing that works, you can set the `compiler-options` from the command line. In my case, much like the OP, I have a `tsconfig.json` with a `module: esnext`. I was able to override on the command line:

Ran on Windows, w/`ts-node` installed globally, but in different shell types:

*bash/mingw64:*
`ts-node --compiler-options={"module":"commonJS"} xxx.ts`

*cmd:*
`ts-node --compiler-options={\"module\":\"commonJS\"} xxx.ts`

Answer (score 1):

On mac

```
"test": "TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS='{\"module\":\"commonjs\"}' mocha --require ts-node/register test/**/*.ts",
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't address the core original question, but goes to the heart of getting mocha with typescript working, so I'll post it here in case it helps others.

We found that some ridiculous backslash escaping was needed to make this work on Windows. It works fine on Mac too, even though Mac doesn't need the same escaping.

Then, additional `ts-node require` directives were critical.

File `package.json`:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "cross-env TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS={\\\"module\\\":\\\"commonjs\\\"} mocha"
  },

  ...

  "mocha": {
    "require": [
      "ts-node/register",
      "tsconfig-paths/register"
    ],
    "watch-files": [
      "./src/**/*.ts",
      "./tests/**/*.spec.ts"
    ],
    "spec": "./tests/**/*.spec.ts"
  }
```