# TS-Node with Mocha doesn't use TS_NODE_PROJECT

Tags: mocha.js, ts-node

I'm having trouble with using the env variable `TS_NODE_PROJECT` when ts-node is used for testing using Mocha.

The project structure looks like this:

```
src/
  main_test.ts
  tsconfig.json
package.json
```

In my test, I want to use an async function, which requires `"lib": ["es2018"]` as a compilation option.

```
// src/main_test.ts
describe('', () => {
    it('test', () => {
        (async function() {})()
    });
});

// src/tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": ["es2018"]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "../node_modules"
  ]
}
```

To run the test, I use this command, but it results in an error:

```
TS_NODE_PROJECT='src' && mocha --require ts-node/register src/*_test.ts
# TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
# error TS2468: Cannot find global value 'Promise'.
# src/main_test.ts(3,10): error TS2705: An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor.  Make sure you have a declaration for the 'Promise' constructor or include 'ES2015' in your `--lib` option.
```

This means that `src/tsconfig.json` is not used. According to [Overriding `tsconfig.json` for ts-node in mocha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40635956/overriding-tsconfig-json-for-ts-node-in-mocha)
 and the ts-node documentation, the command should pass the correct `tsconfig.json` path to ts-node.

Moving `src/tsconfig.json` to project directory and running the same command causes the test to succeed. How can I pass the `tsconfig.json` path to ts-node so that the test compiles correctly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Oh. How embarrassing...

```
TS_NODE_PROJECT='src/tsconfig.json' mocha --require ts-node/register src/*_test.ts
```

Comment: This was very clutch!

Answer (score 1):

I find very useful to move mocha setup in different files so package.json remains clean, you can use a `mocharc` file like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  ignore: [
    './test/helpers/**/*',
    './test/mocha.env.js'
  ],
  require: [
    'test/mocha.env', // init env here
    'ts-node/register'
  ],
  extension: [
    'ts'
  ]
}
```

and then create the file `test/mocha.env.js` (or call it as you wish) with this content:

```js
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test'
process.env.TS_NODE_PROJECT = 'src/tsconfig.json'
```