# Mocha test failing using typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, mocha.js

I have a project where I am using TS and Rollup. My code builds and run fine but when I run the tests via `npm run test` they fail with a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` error message.

Now I know that the issue is with the ES6 syntax because I am using `import` in my test file and it seems that the test is not getting transpiled but not sure why.

My relevant part of package.json:

```
 "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.es.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "watch": "rollup -cw",
    "prepublish": "rollup -c > index.js && BROWSER=true rollup -c > browser.js",
    "clean": "rm -rf dist/",
    "test": "mocha -r ts-node/register src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "testdebug": "mocha --inspect-brk --colors --recursive --require ts-node/register --watch-extensions ts \"**/*spec.ts\" --exclude \"node_modules/**\"",
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json -t codeFrame"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "4.1.7",
    "@types/chai-as-promised": "7.1.0",
    "@types/long": "4.0.0",
    "@types/mocha": "5.2.6",
    "@types/node": "11.9.4",
    "@types/sinon": "7.0.6",
    "@types/sinon-chai": "3.2.2",
    "@types/supertest": "2.0.7",
    "@types/uuid": "3.4.4",
    "chai": "4.2.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "7.1.1",
    "husky": "1.3.1",
    "lint-staged": "8.1.4",
    "mocha": "5.2.0",
    "mocha-jenkins-reporter": "0.4.1",
    "prettier": "1.16.4",
    "rollup": "^1.10.0",
    "rollup-plugin-replace": "^2.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "^0.20.1",
    "sinon": "7.2.3",
    "sinon-chai": "3.3.0",
    "supertest": "3.4.2",
    "ts-node": "8.0.2",
    "tslint": "5.12.1",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "1.18.0",
    "tslint-config-standard": "8.0.1",
    "tslint-microsoft-contrib": "6.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.3.3"
  },
```

My test.spec.ts file:

```
    import { loginUser } from './loginUser'

    console.log(loginUser)
```

My tsconfig file: (I already tried to remove the spec files from exclude but its the same unfortunately)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "es6",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    "outDir": "./dist",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
   },
   "exclude":[
     "node_modules",
     "dist",
     "./**/*.spec.ts",
     "./test/**/*.ts"
   ]
  }
```

My rollup.config file

```
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2'
import replace from 'rollup-plugin-replace'
import pkg from './package.json'
export default {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: [
        {
            file: pkg.main,
            format: 'cjs',
        },
        {
            file: pkg.module,
            format: 'es',
        },
    ],
    external: [
        ...Object.keys(pkg.dependencies || {}),
        ...Object.keys(pkg.peerDependencies || {}),
    ],
    plugins: [
        typescript({
            typescript: require('typescript'),
        }),
        replace({
            'process.browser': !!process.env.BROWSER
        })
    ],
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason that you want the test files to use Typescript? You could have the tests in plain JavaScript that you use to test the module created by Rollup.

Answer (score 0):

Your mocha setup looks correct.

`./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --inspect-brk=9230 -r ts-node/register tests/**/*spec.ts"`

- Did you install `npm i ts-node`?
- Did you consider that `inspect-brk` stops the execution until you continue the execution in the inspector? + check also the port

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by using: `TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS={\\\"module\\\":\\\"commonjs\\\"} mocha -r ts-node/register test/**/*.spec.ts`

more details: [Overriding `tsconfig.json` for ts-node in mocha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40635956/overriding-tsconfig-json-for-ts-node-in-mocha#comment103202638_44343768)