# Change default TypeScript configuration file when run the mocha tests

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js, ts-node

In the question [Overriding `tsconfig.json` for ts-node in mocha](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40635956/4818123)
the only reason for the overriding of the TypeScript configuration file was the changing of the `module` option to `commonjs`. So all suggested solutions were about how to change the `module` option to `commonjs`, not about how to change the TtypeScript configuration.

In my case, I want to change the `include` option. My repository has `Source` and `Test` directories, and I need just to compile the `Source`.

[image]

But if to run mocha tests, it will be the message (with `ts-node/esm` option):

```
ts-node is configured to ignore this file.
If you want ts-node to handle this file, consider enabling the "skipIgnore" option or adjusting your "ignore" patterns.
```

### Repro

I created the [repro](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/Issue-MochaTS_Node-1).
Initially, it was about `TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for D:\XXX\project\node_modules\tsconfig-paths\src\__tests__\config-loader.test.ts` error, but first I need to deal with this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First fix `.mocharc.yaml` to get rid of the `TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for D:\XXX\project\node_modules\tsconfig-paths\src\__tests__\config-loader.test.ts` error. The `.mocharc.yaml` is including everything with `**/*.test.ts` and this includes stuff in `node_modules` too.

Also, `ts-node` is being registered twice. One by the `register: [ts-node/register]` and another one by the `loader: ts-node/esm`. Just use the latter.

Here's the fix:

```yaml
extension:
  - ts

spec: "Tests/**/*.test.ts"

loader: ts-node/esm
```

Finally, to use a different `tsproject.json` for tests with `ts-node`, set the environment variable `TS_NODE_PROJECT` to `'./tsconfig.test.json'` and run `mocha`.

Comment: You have made my day. I find many sources to fix the `TypeError` not knowing that it includes the `node_modules`