# Cannot find module 'ts-node/register'

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js

I want to use mocha to test my TypeScript/Angular2 project.  I tried to use **ts-node** as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35661569/5115768):

```
npm install -g ts-node
```

but when running

```
mocha --require ts-node/register -t 10000 ./**/*.unit.ts
```

I get an error

> Cannot find module 'ts-node/register'

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you install this https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node ?

Comment: I've created a new project, installed Mocha and ts-node, and used your command but did not get the error you report having. Everything worked fine from the get go. There's something you did wrong that you are not showing in your question. I would also say that the 18 upvotes on the answer from which you got this method and the lack of downvotes and comments bringing up the error you got is evidence that *it just works*.

Comment: I had this problem as well. Not sure why this Q has been closed. but installing ts-node locally fixes this. `npm install ts-node --save-dev`

Comment: I would like this question to be reopened as the answer is not a simple one...Anita's comment is the correct answer

Comment: Why was the question closed? It's a valid question.

Comment: It will work if you do not include the `-g` 'global' flag -- it's a path issue.

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Since the answer that works for a lot of people appears to be hidden in the comments, I'll post it as an actual answer to the question, now that it appears the question has been reopened.

> I had this problem as well. Not sure why this Q has been closed. but installing ts-node locally fixes this. `npm install ts-node --save-dev`

Thanks @Anita, as this was the answer that worked for me too.

Comment: You also have to install typescript `npm install typescript --save`

Comment: On my Linux machine I actually needed to install it globally as well `sudo npm install ts-node -g`

Comment: Sometimes you don't want to place `ts-node` in package deps and want to use the global one. For such cases linking a local package to the global one using `npm link ts-node` solves the problem.

Comment: I also wanted to confirm what @Lonely said. After `npm install ts-node --save-dev` I then got an error about typescript, so I installed to devDepenancies: `npm install typescript --save-dev` and now I don't get this error.

Comment: Why does this actually work with locally installed ts code? Why not with just global? Could someone explain it to me? I don't get it

Comment: i did `npm install ts-node`, `npm install ts-node -g`, `npm install ts-node --save-dev`
none works. What other options do I have?

Comment: `npm install typescript --save-dev` - seem to be required for me

Comment: This answer worked perfectly but i don't get it why it works. Any explanation?

Answer (score 26):

Wow, a silly mistake can cost you time. I was facing the same issue when I was trying to debug my `nodejs` application. The mistake I had done was that I have created my `.vscode` folder outside of my `nodejs` app folder(the directory which had `node_modules` in it). When I moved my `.vscode` to that folder, everything work fine. Below is my `launch.json` file.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "index",         
            "args": [
                "src/index.ts"
            ],
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-r",
                "ts-node/register"
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"           
        }
    ],
    "compounds": []
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you don't want to move your vscode folder, use; `./myproj/node_modules/ts-node/register`

Comment: In the end if I moved the directory, upon attempting to run my debug config, the test disappeared from my debug dropdown.. so supplying the relative path as @myol has recommended within my config resolved my issue! Thank you both

Answer (score 5):

I know this is kind of old, but I ran into this too and wanted to offer the solution I'm currently using.

I installed `ts-node` globally using `sudo npm i -g ts-node`. To make this work with mocha, I just had to give mocha the absolute path to the module, like this:

```
mocha -r /usr/lib/node_modules/ts-node/register test/*Test.ts
```

Hope that helps someone else.

Answer (score 3):

Try this command instead:

```
mocha --compilers ts:ts-node/register,tsx:ts-node/register
```

which works for me.

Comment: `--compilers` flag is now deprecated. https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/compilers-deprecation

Comment: Thanks dude, works for me. The solution accepted  in this thread doesn't work though.

Answer (score 2):

I have `mocha` and `ts-node` installed as dev dependencies in my package. I'm also using pnpm. I originally had a `script` for `test` that was defined as:

```
pnpx mocha -r ts-node/register '*.test.ts'
```

When this stopped working with the same error as reported in this question I fixed it by making the `-r` path explicit:

```
pnpx mocha -r ./node_modules/ts-node/register '*.test.ts'
```

I'm still confused as to why the original version stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

Use `/node_modules/ts-node/register` in place of `ts-node/register`. So in your case it'll become:

```
mocha --require /node_modules/ts-node/register -t 10000 ./**/*.unit.ts
```

and make sure ts-node is installed locally in your project like:

```
npm install ts-node @types/node typescript
```

This solution doesn't need you to install ts-node globally. And it works cross platform and for everyone.

Comment: I had the problem only in the Mocha Test Explorer UI extension in VS Code. I needed to add "node_modules/" to get it to work, but still have no idea what caused it in the first place, as it stopped working today without me changing anything (that I know of, so no update or anything)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you rather not install ts-node locally and would prefer to use the globally installed node_module. The following examples show what to do for Windows and assumes you're using NVM.  If not using NVM, replace `NVM_SYMLINK` with `C:\Program Files\nodejs`

Example for command line:

```
node -r "%NVM_SYMLINK%\node_modules\ts-node\register" script.ts arg1 arg2
```

Example for bash:

```sh
node -r "$NVM_SYMLINK/node_modules/ts-node/register" script.ts arg1 arg2
```

Example for vscode launch.config

```
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "utils/roll_browser",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "-r",
        /* Slower startup. Runs full typescript validation */
        // "${env:NVM_SYMLINK}/node_modules/ts-node/register"
        /* Faster startup. Doesn't check types or verify the code is valid */
        "${env:NVM_SYMLINK}/node_modules/ts-node/register/transpile-only"
      ],
      "args": ["${workspaceFolder}/utils/roll_browser.ts", "chromium", "756141"],
    },
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue while using "jasmine-unit-test-generator". I fix it by runing `npm link ts-node`.
you can refer to https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/565

Answer (score 0):

I know that I'm late but I had the same problem today
You have to give to the `--require` flag an absolute path. I had the same error and I solved It by going from this:

```
"script":{
 .....
 "test":"env TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS='{\"module\": \"commonjs\" }' mocha --require /node_modules/ts-node/register 'test/**/*.ts'"
 }
```

To this with a relative path for the flag:

```
"script":{
 .....
 "test":"env TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS='{\"module\": \"commonjs\" }' mocha --require ./node_modules/ts-node/register 'test/**/*.ts'"
 }
```

The key thing is the dot in the `./node_modules`.
Of course you have to have your module installed locally or globally installed and linked to the node project

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the local version of ts-node (the one being used by your project), and instead want to use the global version of ts-node you installed, you can do this...

```bash
which ts-node # to find the path for the global ts-node
```

```json
{
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "ts-node",
      "type": "node",
      "program": "THE_PATH_YOU_GOT_FROM_THE_WHICH_CMD",
      "args": [
        "${relativeFile}"
      ],
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
    }  
  ]
}
```

You don't need to use the node -r runtime argument if you're using your global installation of ts-node.

Answer (score -1):

Switching to node 18 from 16 resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score -5):

```
Error:
module.js:328
    throw err; 
Error: Cannot find module 'ts-node'
```

Solution: Following command solves the issue.

```
<b>npm install ts-node --save-dev</b>
```

(Installs ts-node as a development dependency for your project)