# How to make Typescript/ts-node accept the lookbehind assertion (an ECMAScript 2018 feature)?

Tags: node.js, regex, typescript

I have a regex that uses lookbehind:

```
(?<!\S)\'\S(.*?)\S\'(?!\S)
```

It's an [ES2018](https://2ality.com/2017/05/regexp-lookbehind-assertions.html) feature.

I'm also using Typescript, so I run my code with [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node).

When running the code, I got this error:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<!\S)\'\S(.*?)\S\'(?!\S)/:
Invalid group
```

Doing this, however, runs the code successfully:

> node --harmony script.js

I tried adding this to my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "ES2018" // I also tried es2018. No luck.
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "out",
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```

But I'm getting the same error.

Any advice?

**Note:** I updated `node` to version 13 via `nvm`. Doing `node script.js` works, but not `ts-node script.ts`. I already have the latest version of `ts-node`, so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Running `ts-node src/index.ts` where `index.ts` is `const pattern = /(?<!\S)\'\S(.*?)\S\'(?!\S)/;
console.log(pattern.test('foo'));` and my tsconfig.json is identical to yours results in the code running with no errors, for me

Comment: @CertainPerformance Hm, maybe the problem is my Node version? Mine is v8.9.0. (I don't think the issue is TypeScript or ts-node, because I installed them recently.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I installed the lastest node version via nvm. Same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lookbehind was first introduced to Node sometime in version 8, but since (back then) it was an experimental feature, it required the `--harmony` flag (which enables experimental features, such as new syntax, which are not considered 100% reliable and stable yet). Getting ts-node to run node with the `harmony` flag is a bit ugly - you have to run native Node and have it preload ts-node, something like:

```
node --harmony -r ts-node/register index.ts
```

(make sure ts-node is [installed locally](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40910864))

Lookbehind graduated out of Harmony [in node 10](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/02/regexp-features-regular-expressions/), so you'll be able to run lookbehind without the harmony flag if you update Node to version 10. (It looks like version [9.11.2](https://node.green/#ES2018-features--RegExp-Lookbehind-Assertions) also supports it)

Comment: Weird. I switched to Node 13 via nvm and installed ts-node again: `npm install ts-node -g
/home/alex/.nvm/versions/node/v13.7.0/bin/ts-node` I'm getting the same error.

Comment: The global flag might be causing the issue if you also have a local installation - try installing it locally too

Comment: Ah, doing node `script.js` works. So the problem is `ts-node` ... And the harmony flag doesn't work with `ts-node`. I wonder how to fix that.

Comment: Never mind. I updated everything, and now everything works. Thanks.