# Configure Mocha sidebar for typescript test file

Tags: node.js, express, testing, mocha.js

How can I configure [Mocha sidebar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maty.vscode-mocha-sidebar) for my project?

My test files are located in this path: `/src/Gamma.Tests/*.ts`.

Also I set these in settings.json file:

```
"mocha.files.glob": "src/Gamma.Tests/**/*.ts",
    "mocha.requires": [
        "ts-node/register"
    ]
```

I have installed these packages already:

```
npm install typescript --save-dev
npm install ts-node --save-dev
npm install -g ts-node
npm install -g typescript
```

**The error in VSCode:**

> Failed to run Mocha due to error message:
> "   Cannot find module 'ts-node/register' Require stack:
>
> - c:\Users\rouhi.vscode\extensions\maty.vscode-mocha-sidebar-0.22.2\lib\worker\findtests.js
>   "    error trace can be found in the ouput channel .
>   for more help:

How can I solve this problem?

---

**Notice:**

in package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha -r ts-node/register src/Gamma.Tests/**/*.ts",
    "start": "tsc && node ./build/server.js"
  },
```

There is no problem, when I run `npm run test`

[image: vscode environment]

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40910864/cannot-find-module-ts-node-register) is relevant to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution for Mocha Test Explorer

I had the same problem using [mocha sidebar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maty.vscode-mocha-sidebar). Intrigued by [this demo](https://youtu.be/QsupPG1RGVQ), I installed the [Mocha Test Explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hbenl.vscode-mocha-test-adapter) extension and faced the same problem (among others).

It didn't work for me since I had the whole "backend" project in a subfolder of the project root. The solution for me was to **set up a multi-root project in VSCode**:

- Click on `File -> Add Folder to Workspace`
- Choose your subfolder, e.g. `backend`
- Click on `File -> Save Workspace As` and save the `workspace.code-workspace` file to the `.vscode` folder in your project root.
- In your subfolder (e.g. `backend`), create a new folder `.vscode` and place a new `settings.json` file with the following content:

```json
{
    "mochaExplorer.files": "test/**/*.ts",
    "mochaExplorer.require": "ts-node/register"
}
```

If you still encounter problems with `ts-node/register`, this [post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40910864/cannot-find-module-ts-node-register) might be useful. For tips using a multi-root workspace in VSCode, see this great [blog post](https://medium.com/rewrite-tech/visual-studio-code-tips-for-monorepo-development-with-multi-root-workspaces-and-extension-6b69420ecd12).